# Date field giving required error on validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have created a model in my asp.net MVC 3 website and have a property named DateOpened:

```
  [Column("Date Opened")]
        [Display(Name = "Date Opened:")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime DateOpened { get; set; }
```

I didn't apply [Required] data annotation to it, but when I try to save the form, It says required field. In database it is null.

Please suggest solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's normal. DateTime is a value type meaning that it will always require a value. The model metadata provider in ASP.NET MVC automatically adds the required attribute to non-nullable data types. You could use a nullable DateTime:

```
[Column("Date Opened")]
[Display(Name = "Date Opened:")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DateOpened { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I modified the model but now I am getting this cast error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime?' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) on pages where I am using DateOpened

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, how are you using this property? In order to access the value of a nullable type you need to use its `.Value` property: `DateOpened.Value`.