# mvc data annotation validator for datetime always shows required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

when I submit my form, Termination date field shows "Termination Date field is required" even though I haven't defined it as required anywhere.

my model is defined as:

```
[Display(Name = "Termination Date")]
public DateTime TerminationDate { get; set; }
```

razor code is:

```
 <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Posting.TerminationDate)
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Posting.TerminationDate, new { @class = "form-control" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Posting.TerminationDate)
  </div>
```

I do not want any type of validation on this field. How can I do that?

Comment: Make it nullable `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date field giving required error on validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239451/date-field-giving-required-error-on-validation)

Comment: I think [Date field giving required error on validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239451/date-field-giving-required-error-on-validation) post has the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Make the property nullable

```
DateTime? or Nullable<DateTime>
```

Or reconfigure the convention

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```