# ASP.NET MVC5 Datetime required?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm try to work on a comment section and i've made it so a user can post a comment, but I also want a time stamp. So this is how my model looks like

```
    public class Suggestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Suggestion")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public DateTime WhenPosted { get; set; }

    public Suggestion()
    {
        WhenPosted = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

How ever doing this will end up with the user having to enter the date him self which removes the point of having it.

So I made a constructor that looks like this:

```
public Suggestion()
    {
        WhenPosted = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Which works just fine the WhenPosted variable holds the right Time.

How ever when a user is going to post his comment it tells me this:
The WhenPosted field is required.

Which I find rather weird as I do not use the `[Required]` attribute.

I'm aware not I can use the nullable DateTime? How ever that allows my user to not enter a DateTime but it also means my ends up null in my database, but I want the DateTime to be automaticly set to the time it was posted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date field giving required error on validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239451/date-field-giving-required-error-on-validation)

Comment: Try using Nullable DateTime i.e DateTime?

Comment: I'm aware not I can use the nullable DateTime? How ever that allows my user to not enter a DateTime but it also means my ends up null in my database, but I want the DateTime to be automaticly set to the time it was posted.

Comment: So let them send a null value and fill it in when it gets back to the server

Comment: Not sure how I would do that, when debugging my WhenPosted variable holds the right value, but it sends it as null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All value types (including `DateTime`) when posted back to the MVC controller, should have a value.

To achieve the needs as per your requirement, I would probably do something like

```
        private DateTime _date;    

        public DateTime Date
        {
            get {
                // by default the date was getting set to 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
                if (_date == null || _date.ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
                {
                    return _date = DateTime.Now;
                }    
                return _date; 
            }
            set {

                _date = value; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of comparing the .ToString() output, which could change depending on the thread culture, I would compare _date to DateTime.MinValue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just assign a default value to the property it should work fine.

```
private DateTime _date = DateTime.Now;    //default value assigned here.
public DateTime Date {
    get { return _date; }
    set { _date = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, if you want to use the code in your question, would be to round-trip the property value.

Within your `<form>` element:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m. WhenPosted)
```